# XamlReader official code snippet throwing exception for me

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, xamlreader

I'm building a Windows 8 app, and want to parse some XAML from a web service to put in a RichTextBlock. I'm trying to use XamlReader to use this, but [this code from Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlreader.load.aspx#code-snippet-2) is throwing an exception in my environment.

```
string xaml = "<Ellipse Name=\"EllipseAdded\" Width=\"300.5\" Height=\"200\" Fill=\"Red\" \"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"/>";
object ellipse = Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xaml);
```

When executing the second line, I get the exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

WinRT information: illegal qualified name character [Line: 1 Position: 68]

Additional information: Unspecified error
```

My version of VS is Microsoft Visual C# 2012 (Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2012 Version 11.0.51106.01, Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.5.50709). The documentation says Windows 8 should support the load method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there's a typo in their XAML - they're missing an `xmlns=` before the namespace URI:

```
string xaml = "<Ellipse"
   + " Name=\"EllipseAdded\" Width=\"300.5\" Height=\"200\" Fill=\"Red\""
   + " xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"/>";
```

*(Line wrapped for readability.)*

Comment: Yup, that did it. Oddly, back when I was using my own code instead of copy-pasting from Microsoft, I included the xmlns= and it still choked, but at least I have SOMEWHERE to go from now. Thanks!

Comment: You can use these quotes `'` instead of `"`, it works in UWP.